# Using SSO with multiple webapplications with their own membership implementation

Tags: .net, asp.net-membership, claims-based-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to connect multiple webapplications through SSO.
I've setup Thinktecture v2 and it's already in use for some other projects. So that works fine.
Each of the applications are already using the .Net Membership and I don't want to merge all there users in the Thinktecture database.

Who can help me out?

Comment: Are they all ASP.Net Web Form or ASP.Net MVC/Web API? What .Net versions are they?

Comment: For now they're all ASP.Net webform using .net 4.5.